# Help with a relative clause + を中心に

Tags: words, translation, relative-clauses

Here's the sentence:

> あるいはまた、東南アジアを**中心に**世界各地で活躍するいわゆる華僑勢力の多くが福建省出身者である事実を見ても、福建人たちの「海外雄飛」のパワーを知ることができる。

My rough translation is something like:

> "Moreover, looking also at the fact that a large part of [...] are natives of Fujian, it is possible to understand the power of people from Fujian in going overseas"

What troubles me most is that 華僑勢力: shouldn't 多く refer to 華僑 ("a large number of the so-called overseas Chinese merchants")?

Also, does

> 東南アジアを**中心に**世界各地で活躍する

mean "active all over the world and particularly in South-East Asia"?  How would I use this X を中心に Y pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

中心 means center and を中心に(して) means "as center". Like you suggested,

> 東南アジアを中心に世界各地で活躍する
>   active all around the world, with South-East Asia as center of activity

Also, 多く should not refer to 華僑, 多く stands for many, in the sense of many people.

My rough translation would be

> あるいはまた、東南アジアを中心に世界各地で活躍するいわゆる華僑勢力の多くが福建省出身者である事実を見ても、福建人たちの「海外雄飛」のパワーを知ることができる。
>   Moreover, considering the fact that many of the so-called 華僑勢力 (Chinese merchants overseas force) are active all around the world, South-East Asia being the heart of their activity, one can understand the Fujian people's power that comes from going overseas.